# Weblink with a preview

Tags: beamer

How can I insert this [Link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13226-021-00100-0) to a beamer presentation with a preview?

Comment: Regardless of beamer, if you just want to display the website may be including a screenshot as graphics is easier and suffisient. E.g. you don't need a network connection during presentation.